# Is passing a model ID to the controller through hidden fields safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

Imagine I have a view that takes a model of type employee. Employee is defined like so:
Employee{
ID int,
Employee Name string
}
If I wanted to update an employee in the database I have to pass the model to the action.
UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
Defining the employee ID in a hidden field would be a security risk wouldn't it?
Someone could easily go into the inspector and pass whatever ID they like and the information will be updated for that employee.

Comment: Even microsoft templates does that. Who are your users anyway? You could simply just add audit to identify who made that change. Customers don't usually do that. Plus how would they identify other's employee id?

Comment: I guess it depends on your requirements. Is this user editing his own employee profile? Or is this user editing from a list of user profiles?

Comment: MVC has an inbuilt verification method for controls rendered, as @JerdineSabio suggested, you can audit change, add an antiforgery token, etc,. This should prevent malicious Id's from being updated

Comment: Be wary of overbinding, and reading or writing records that the user shouldn't have permission to. Basically, assume an attacker can read your source code. If they carefully construct form values by hand, what is the worst they could do?

Comment: I do have anti forgery token submitted with the form. That's not my issue, my issue is I can replace the value of the hidden field with any ID. The  token is still valid and the form will be submitted successfully. It will update the wrong profile though.